# How to refer to console application projects in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have created 2 console projects using .NET Core 3.0 and I have removed program.cs file in the 2nd project and add that project as a reference project to 1st one.

While compiling, I am getting the error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point".

Can anyone explain the how the referencing 2 projects works in C#?

Comment: A console mode project requires a Main() method.  The most obvious way to do this is to create a class library project instead.  Or not remove Main()

Comment: You mean all the dependency projects are created as a class library project instead of console project

Comment: What type of project are you using?  A Console application requires a main while a class project does not have a main.  Change your project type to a class project which does not require main.

Answer (score 2):

The entry-point (aka `Main`) needs to exist in any console project (i.e. an exe). Normally in this scenario you would have:

- some library project

  - (has some code)
- some console project

  - references "some library project"
  - has an entry-point (`Main`)
  - (probably has some other code)

It sounds like you just want to make the first project a library project rather than a console project, which can be done by **removing** `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` from the csproj.